# Массово добавить значение в существующие строки из XML в MS sql

Tags: xml, sql-server, xslt

Есть `XML` файл с `1000` строк, где есть данные пользователя и новые значения ключа активации для них, как добавить эти данные в базу `MS SQL` где уже есть эти пользователи, и нужно просто заменить старые значения ключей на новые

Comment: Какая у Вас версия SQL Server и какими инструментами допустимо пользоваться, есть ли, например, возможность (и необходимость) написать утилиту для этого?

Comment: ms sql server 2008 r2, можно написать утилиту, я бы применил bulkinsert, но он массово заружает только новые значения, как его заставить добавлять значения, по данным пользователя я не нашел

Answer (score 2):

А чем вам обычный UPDATE из XML переменной не подходит?
1000 строк не такая уж цифра, чтобы думать об какой-то хитрой оптимизации..

для примера накидал простой скрипт:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Users', 'U')IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Users;
```

--создаём табличку с полдьзователями

```
CREATE TABLE #Users(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
```

--добавляем 100 000 пользователей

```
;WITH CTE100000 AS(SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM CTE100000 WHERE N<100000)
INSERT #Users
SELECT NEWID() FROM CTE100000
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

DECLARE
  @xml XML
```

--генерируем xml с 1000 строк

```
;WITH CTE1000 AS(SELECT 1 N, 100 Id UNION ALL SELECT N+1, Id + 100 FROM CTE1000 WHERE N<1000)
SELECT @xml = (
  SELECT N [@Id], NEWID()[@Value] FROM CTE1000
  FOR XML PATH('row'), ROOT('root')
)
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)

SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

--обновляем данные из xml

```
UPDATE U
  SET Value = T.Value
FROM(
  SELECT T.c.value('@Id', 'int') as Id, T.c.value('@Value', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') as Value
  FROM @xml.nodes('/root/row') T(c)
)T
  INNER JOIN #Users U ON U.Id = T.Id
OPTION(FORCE ORDER)
```

Результат:

```
/*
Время синтаксического анализа и компиляции SQL Server: 
 время ЦП = 63 мс, истекшее время = 126 мс.

Время работы SQL Server:
   Время ЦП = 15 мс, затраченное время = 16 мс.

(строк обработано: 1000)
*/
```

Как видим обновление 1000 строк происходит меньше, чем 200ms. Куда вам быстрее?

Единственное, что хочется отметить, это обязательный индекс по #Users.Id и гарантированный пользовательский порядок соединения в операторе `UPDATE`, заданный опцией `FORCE ORDER`, чтобы этот индекс правильно использовать. (хотя сервер тут и сам бы справился)

**UPD:** или у вас проблема с тем, чтобы именно прочитать xml из файла и передать на сервер? Параметром хранимой процедуры, например.

**UPD:** если в xml файле есть данные о пользователях, которые отсутствуют в таблице пользователей, их можно добавить оператором `INSERT`, примерно таким:

```
INSERT #Users(Id, Value)
SELECT T.Id, T.Value
FROM(
  SELECT T.c.value('@Id', 'int') as Id, T.c.value('@Value', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') as Value
  FROM @xml.nodes('/root/row') T(c)
)T
  LEFT JOIN #Users U ON U.Id = T.Id
WHERE U.Id IS NULL
OPTION(FORCE ORDER)
```

Чтобы обновить старые и вставить новые одним запросом, можно использовать оператор [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510625.aspx). Поизучайте хотя бы ради академического интереса, может понравится.

Comment: Дело в том что записей в самой таблице около 100 тысяч, xml файл имеет в себе только фио и др, и по этим данным надо сверить куда вставлять код, и как это сделать нету понимания...

Comment: @AizenSouske, ну и что? Добавьте индекс по фио и др. Скорость от количества строк в таблице не изменится. Тут всё дело в количестве строк в xml файле, для каждой строки из xml файла сервер по индексу в таблице пользователей ищет строку, которую нужно обновить. Изменил в своём скрипте количество пользователей на 100 000. Анализ плана стал чуть дольше выполнятся, а вот время выполнения запроса так и осталось менее 20ms. Повторяю вопрос. Куда вам меньше?:)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сейчас,время обработки запросы не играло роли, дело именно в понимание как делать, вообщем еще раз спасибо =)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, с чего вы взяли что запрос на синхронизацию с xml один? С чего вы взяли что этого индекса ещё нет? С чего вы взяли, что этот индекс не пригодится для других задач поиска по пользователям? Вполне естественный индекс.

Comment: @pegoopik чот я так и не смог разобраться в этом коде, xml файл у меня лежит отдельно на моем компьютере, база лежит на сервере, доступ к серверу есть. Зачем генерировать еще один новый xml во время создание таблицы, и если без этого никак, то как туда вставить данные из моего xml чтобы он их обновил...

Comment: @AizenSouske, всё верно, вам не нужно генерировать xml, это я для примера, чтобы была понятна производительность. Как вы присоединяетесь к серверу? Как вариант, вы можете передать xml как параметр хранимой процедуры, которая и будет из параметра обновлять вашу таблицу.

Comment: @AizenSouske, если вы хотите вручную один раз это сделать, можете скопировать текст xml из файла и вставить его в вашу среду разработки: `declare @xml xml = '<текст xml файла>'`

Comment: UPDATE tmp.PEOPLEtest
  SET ka = T.ka
FROM(
  SELECT T.c.value('@FAM', 'varchar') as FAM, T.c.value('@IM', 'varchar') as IM, T.c.value('@OT', 'varchar') as OT,
  T.c.value('@DR', 'datetime') as DR, T.c.value ('@SS', 'varchar') as ka
  
  FROM @xml.nodes('/root/row') T(c)
)T

INNER JOIN tmp.PEOPLEtest  ON tmp.PEOPLEtest.FAM = T.FAM вот такой код написал, но он не работает как надо, как правильно добавить все параметры в иннер джоин

Comment: А нет все разобрался, спасибо всем большое за помощь